# Файл kivy не запускается из консоли

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

Всё было установлено точно по порядку и корректно по сайту kivy.org, но скрипт с киви всё ровно не запускается с консоли. Что то не то с sdl2. Что с чем там не дружит? Если не через консоль запускать, а через среду разрабтки то всё работает.

```
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/lemon/.kivy /logs/kivy_20-12-24_19.txt
   [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0.dev0
   [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/lemon/kivy/kivy/__init__.py"
   [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24)
   [GCC 8.4.0]
   [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/lemon/kivy_venv/bin/python3"
   [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
   [INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.2
   [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil,  img_ffpyplayer
   [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
   [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'No available video device'
  File "/home/lemon/kivy/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
    File "/home/lemon/kivy/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 152, in    __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/home/lemon/kivy/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 982, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/home/lemon/kivy/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 289, in create_window
    self.get_gl_backend_name())
   File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 112, in   kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
   File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 74, in      kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die  

   x11 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
   File "/home/lemon/kivy/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 62, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

   [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: А картинка видна?

Comment: Неа, да и это тоже не рекомендуется, т.к. неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Ошибки тоже текстом в вопрос

Comment: Покажите еще как вы его запускаете

Comment: А что такое стек с ошибкой? Как тогда показать проблему?

Comment: Когда у вас ошибка произошла там вывалится полотно текста, с текстом исключения и кучей функций. Это и есть трасса стека. На вашем скриншоте оно и было

Comment: Ну я написал текст ошибки как он был в консоле. Как сделать ещё лучше уже не понимаю. Я видел как у других красиво выведена информация из консоли в отдельном окне, но как они это сделали не догоняю

Comment: `текст ошибки` а всё остальное? Я писал про функции и прочее. Т.е. вам нужно скопировать из консоли **весь текст** и его в вопрос засунуть. И то, что вы написали это не точная причина проблемы. В трассе стека видно, что он не смог найти модуль для x11

Comment: не даёт вывести всю ошибку, пишет про 4 отступа и сделать их не даёт

Comment: Непонятно причем тут ошибка про отступы, это скорее к коду питону относится. Просто выделите весь текст из консоли в скриншоте и скопируйте в ваш вопрос, окружив его ```

Comment: перед ошибкой напишите ``` и после ошибки также

Comment: Кажется, ваше сообщение содержит код, не оформленный соответствующим образом. Пожалуйста, выделите весь код 4 отступами с помощью кнопки на панели инструментов или воспользуйтесь комбинацией клавиш CTRL+K. Чтобы получить дополнительную справку по редактированию, нажмите значок [?] в панели инструментов.     Вот надое он мне с этим сообщением. И кавычки не помогают

Comment: Разобрался в общем